# Fetch data from multiple sheets using Google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to **fetch data from multiple spreadsheet's**. All Sheet's are stored in same folder. Have to fetch data **in one master sheet** from only specific files **by file name.** I have written below script. It's working fine if we enter only one file name in specified range (in master sheet tab) (getSheetByName) but showing error while trying to fetch data for multiple files.
**Showing error - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"**
Below is Script -

```
function get_compiled_data() {    
  var filelist = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FileName");  
  var filelists = filelist.getRange("A2:A").getValues();  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1li9hBP_W5gPkb_ASKqin4j1ZGEn1Gvji");   
  var fileindex = folder.getFilesByName(filelists);  
  var file;
  var filetype;
  var sheetID;
  var collect_data = [];
  var data;    
  while (fileindex.hasNext()) {    
    file = fileindex.next();    
    filetype = file.getMimeType();    
    if (filetype === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){      
      sheetID = file.getId();      
      data = getData(sheetID);      
      data = data.map(function(r){return r.concat([file.getName()]);});      
      collect_data = collect_data.concat(data);      
    }      
  }  
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Compiled_Data");
  target.getRange("A2:AX").clearContent();
  target.getRange(2, 1, collect_data.length, collect_data[0].length).setValues(collect_data);  
}

function getData (sheetID) {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  var tab = sheet.getSheets()[0];
  var data = tab.getRange("A3:AX" + tab.getLastRow()).getValues();
  return data;  
}
```

Comment: Looks like your while loop is not getting executed, causing collect_data to be empty list and hence error on `collect_data[0].length`. Now I will like you to check the line `var filelists = filelist.getRange("A2:A").getValues();` again and see if range is correct.
`

Comment: What does range `A2:A` means ?

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for reviewing query.
I have checked line `var filelists = filelist.getRange("A2:A").getValues();`
It's working fine if changed to `var filelists = filelist.getRange("A2").getValues();`
But in this case we can enter only 1 file name as a input in cell A2. I have to fetch data from multiple sheets.
Please suggest modifications in script.

Comment: @Ghost `A2:A` is data range in google sheet tab "FileName" here we have enter file names from which data need to be fetched.

Comment: Here is how you can do that 
`var drng = filelist.getDataRange();var range = filelist.getRange(2,1, drng.getLastRow()-1,drng.getLastColumn());var filelists  = range.getValues();`

Comment: @Ghost I have modified query as you suggested, It's working when I enter file name in cell `A1`.
If we enter data in `A1`  and `A2` to fetch data from 2 different sheets then it's not working showing same error - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: My profile has my twitter link. You can DM me on twitter and we can have a chat and then I can comeback and write answer here.

Comment: Did you write the script?

Comment: @TheMaster - Some part of the script I have copied from net and modified it as per my requirements.

Comment: @TheMaster - Thanks for your feedback.
I never claimed for ownership of this query. I have just copied the basics (which is common in every query) for reference and rest I have modified by my own.
I have not copy-pasted from any resource. That's why I am getting this error.
I'm not a professional programmer. Just trying to use this query for my personal use.
Comments on error solution are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You are providing a 2D array to [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)), when you should be providing a string. Because of this, the code never enters the `while` block and `collect_data` remains an empty array, causing `collect_data[0]` to be `undefined`, and producing the observed error when trying to access its `length`.

When you were looking for a single file name you were probably using `getValue()`, which retrieves a single value, which can be a string, which can be used in `getFilesByName`. `getValues()` returns a 2D array instead, so you should adapt your code so that it iterates through each value returned by `getValues()`.

#### Solution:

Edit the `getValues()` line and wrap all the actions made from `getFilesByName` inside a loop the following way:

```js
function get_compiled_data() {
  var filelist = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FileName");      
  var filelists = filelist.getRange(2, 1, filelist.getLastRow() - 1).getValues(); 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER-ID");
  filelists.forEach(fileName => {
    var fileindex = folder.getFilesByName(fileName[0]);
    // Rest of code
  });
});
```

#### Reference:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())